# How to refresh or update specific row in recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am having a `RecyclerView` which is populating list of objects.Each object has one image and a comment. I want to update the comment on a specific row. I dont want to refresh the whole `RecyclerView's Adapter`. I just want to update or refresh that specific row. How can I achieve it? Below is my implementation. Am I doing it write ?

This method is in my `Adapter`: **UPDATED**

```
public void updateComment(String comment,int position){
    this.mList.get(position).setCommentText(comment);
    notifyItemChanged(position,this.mList);
}
```

From my Activity I am calling the above method like this:

```
adapter.updateComment("Great",1);
```

**UPDATE:**

As per the suggestion by **pskink**. I implemented this:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CellViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
        if(payloads.isEmpty()){
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder,position,payloads);
        }else{
            for (Object payload : payloads) {
                if (payload instanceof MyMemo) {
                    holder.bindComment((MyMemo) payload);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The `bindComment()` method in my `ViewHolder`:

```
private void bindComment(MyMemo payload) {
            comment.setText(payload.getCommentText());
        }
```

Comment: `notifyItemChanged` using it to update specific item is fine. but where you are calling `adapter.updateComment()`. that matters

Comment: if you do not want to "update" the whole row use "payload" parameter in `notifyItemChanged()` method

Comment: Already mentioned above in the post. I am calling the `updateComment()` from the `Activity` using the Adapter's object.

Comment: Can you elaborate @pskink

Comment: use `notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)` method

Comment: Here I am passing a string. What should I replace with ? I am new to this. Please bare with me. Any link or little more elaboration would be of great help. @pskink

Comment: have you read `RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload)` method's documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: I have updated my post as per your suggestion. Is this fine ? @pskink

Comment: yes, i think its fine

Comment: Thanks it worked @pskink

Comment: @pskink you can summarise your comments and add it as answer. I will accept it. :)